# Querying an API and redirecting to a results page for a Search bar (component) on a React app

Tags: reactjs, axios, parceljs, reach-router

So I'm having this difficulty trying to build my Search component to query data from my API request via Axios. Right now it just populates an alert box.

It should do a few things, compare the data from the query with the data from the API, pass matched data as props into a results page and redirect to that results page to show those results. The app is deployed here https://suite-search-lk.surge.sh

How should I go about this? Appreciate any help :D

```js
class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("The following value was submitted: " + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SearchDiv>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="searchBoxWrapper">
          <div>
            <input
              className="searchQuery"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              placeholder="Teacher"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="submitWrapper">
            <input className="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Search" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </SearchDiv>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far, apart from the code you provided. Is there a specific issue you are having? is there an error? is it not doing a specific thing but rather doing a different one?

Comment: All the search does right now is populate an alert box. To begin I'd like to redirect to another page via Reach-Router passing the data that was queried.

Comment: And have you tried [looking at the official examples from react router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) ?

Comment: Not in detail, would you advise me to switch from reach-router to react-router?

Comment: Definitely. But I'm still lost on what is the real question here...

Comment: Awesome, I'll check it out. Basically, how do I build my search functionality on the homepage - https://suite-search-lk.surge.sh/

Comment: I think the best way for getting answers in SO is to try coding first, and if you encounter any issues, errors, or are stuck because some part of your code is not working, then you can ask a Question, and for sure people will help you and guide you through.